# Andengine - creating a simple polygon body

Tags: c#, java, andengine

I'm trying to learn AndEngine, i made a program in Visual STudio that I can make my polygon vertices.
But i just can't figure out how to add it to the physics world..

```
Sprite cartman = new Sprite(50, 50, ballTextureRegion,
            this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    cartman.setRotation(50);
    final FixtureDef PLAYER_FIX = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(10.0f,

    .5f, 0.3f);

    float[] vertices = new float[] { 16, 20, 16, 20, 39, 4, 69, 8, 83, 22,
            85, 44, 97, 56, 98, 68, 95, 69, 91, 78, 88, 82, 88, 91, 12, 91,
            8, 76, 4, 69, 0, 60, 14, 44, 13, 30 };
    for (int i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++)
        vertices[i] /= PhysicsConstants.PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT;
    PolygonShape ps = new PolygonShape();
    ps.set(vertices);


     .....

    this.scene.attachChild(cartman);

    physicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(cartman,
            body, true, false));
```

I can't understand what is a iShape..
Can anybody help me?

Comment: Ishape is nothing but sprite extend class Entity indicating in which shape you want to create body. place your sprite where Ishape parameter  is Exist.If you want to get vertices for a body you can use  Physics vertics helper tool.

Comment: You can get from this link: https://code.google.com/p/andengine-vertex-helper/downloads/list

Comment: @Rama i can't... Description Resource Path Location Type
The method createPolygonBody(PhysicsWorld, IShape, Vector2[], BodyDef.BodyType, FixtureDef) in the type PhysicsFactory is not applicable for the arguments (PhysicsWorld, Sprite, float[], BodyDef.BodyType, FixtureDef)